# Passing on value from carousel to another carousel javascript?

Tags: carousel

Is there any good way of achieving this?

My problem is that when I select something in carousel 1 the page is being refreshed and the items in carousel 2 which would have been choosen dependent on what I choose in carousel 1 is being selected. But since the page refreshes the selected item in carousel 1 is no longer selected..

A bit of catch 22, cause if I set the code not to refresh the page I can select everything but carousel 2 never gets updated dependent on what was choosen in carousel 1..

Anyone have had a similar problem?

Must be some solution to this =)

Answer (score 0):

If the selection triggers a link you can add some GET parameters to express what you just selected. Once the page reloads you can read them and build your page's view state accordingly (like: http://mypage.tld/carousel.html?selected=1).

http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/